# Is the Web App still running in the background after switching tabs in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, web-services

In the background does the app still running even though I'm not currently on that tab, or when I move between tabs, the current tab I was, in is getting paused and after I open that tab again it makes a request to the server to get the newer changes from the database?

Edit: The problem which I currently have is:
I have an expiration timer where the reservation needs to be closed after 5 min if there is no activity, now if I open a new tab and come back after e.g. 10 min, the reservation sometimes is closed and it shows good on the front end and back end, sometimes the reservation will close on the backend but the front end will not be updated.

If I'm on that tab then everything works, but when I switch tabs and come back after some time I have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your react app should still be running in the background and switching tabs should not trigger re-renders (unless you programmed it specifically like that)

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload a file to Google Drive and swich tabs and see if uploading still contunies